# Ignore Typescript errors in Webpack-dev-server

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have inherited an angular+Typescript project. The dev environment used gulp's webserver and I am trying to switch over to webpack-dev-server so that we can enable hot-module-replacement.

When I run webpack-dev-server from our build/ directory, the command fails, listing about 700 TypeScript errors. We would rather not fix them. Is there any way to use webpack-dev-server even with TypeScript errors?

My understanding was that webpack should still correctly create the build file and start the dev-server even if typescript errors occur, unless you enable the webpack-fail-plugin, which I do not have enabled.

Here is my current webpack.config.js file:

```
'use strict';
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");

var config = {
    entry: {
        build:  './app/core/bootstrap.ts',
        //adminbuild: './app/core/adminbootstrap.ts',
        //report: './app/core/reportbootstrap.ts',
        vendor: ["angular", "angular-material"]
    },

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        publicPath: '',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.jsx', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        preloaders: [
           /* {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'tslint'
            }*/
        ],

        loaders: [
        ...
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ts'
            },
        ...
        ],
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score -4):

> unless you enable the webpack-fail-plugin, which I do not have enabled.

Not true. Webpack 2 fails builds on typescript errors by default.

## More

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-fail-plugin mentions this fact `DEPRECATED: This is default behaviour in Webpack 2.x, you don't need this plugin anymore.`

Suggestion: Fix the TypeScript errors.

Comment: This is NOT true. Webpack 2 does not fail build on typescript error. The TS loader itself still fails to propagate TS errors by throwing them to webpack, hence, webpack 2 has not solved this issue.