# How to ignore typescript errors when compile by webpack production mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

## environment

webpack 4.41.2

typescript 3.7.2

## problem

When I compile files by webpack development mode, there is no problem.
But when I compile by production mode, there is a lot of errors and I can't compile.

## destination

find the way how to ignore typescript errors when webpack compiles by production mode

## code

▼webpack.config.js (js part)

```
{
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
        filename: "index.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "ts-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: "react-svg-loader",
                options: {
                    svgo: {
                        plugins: [
                            { removeTitle: false }
                        ],
                        floatPrecision: 2
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(vert|frag|glsl)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'webpack-glsl-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },
},
```

▼ tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ],
    "removeComments": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false
  }
}
```

### error content

```
ERROR in /var/www/hoge/src/index.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/hoge/src/index.tsx(56,33)
      TS2322: Type '(page: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'void'.

ERROR in /var/www/hoge/src/about/index.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/hoge/src/about/index.tsx(15,48)
      TS2339: Property 'appRef' does not exist on type 'About'.

ERROR in /var/www/hoge/src/gallery/index.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/hoge/src/gallery/index.tsx(8,27)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './picturesData'.

ERROR in /var/www/hoge/src/gallery/index.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/hoge/src/gallery/index.tsx(9,9)
      TS2529: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'. Compiler reserves name 'Promise' in top level scope of a module containing async functions.

...and other almost similar 40 errors
```

## What I've tried so far

・check similer post in Internet like these
[Ignore Typescript errors in Webpack-dev-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852966/ignore-typescript-errors-in-webpack-dev-server)
[How to ignore typescript errors with webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433442/how-to-ignore-typescript-errors-with-webpack)
but it doesn't help me

・add this code to tsconfig.js

```
"no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
"no-unused-variable": false,
```

but error "Unknown compiler option"

Comment: Have you tried `strict: false` ?

Comment: I added "strict": false" in tsconfig.json, but result is still the same.  Maybe i misunderstood something??

Comment: Solution by @ArnaudClaudel works for me too in Quasar framework 1.14.1 using Vue 2.6. Finally rid of all these errors

Answer (score 22):

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: you should explain what your code does and how it helps the author of the question.

Comment: Adding `options: { transpileOnly: true }` solved the issue for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

use `ignoreDiagnostics` to ignore certain TypeScript errors, but this is more applicable when you just want to run code

```
{
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  use: "ts-loader",
  options: {
    ignoreDiagnostics: [2322]
  }
},
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader#ignorediagnostics

Comment: 2322 is the EXACT error that's giving me headaches. The line it's pointing to and the message makes no sense, and also it happens randomly! Sometimes my build succeeds, other times it fails with this error, even when I make zero changes to the source code. Thanks for a solution for this absolute headache.

Comment: When I try this I get: "Error: Compiling RuleSet failed: A Rule must not have a 'options' property when it has a 'use' property". But this seems to work:   use: [
    {
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      options: {
        ignoreDiagnostics: [2322],
      },
    },
  ],